# OPCUA-client wont open

Tags: python, opc-ua

Iam trying to open the opcua client on ubuntu 14.04.6 and i get this error:

```
cryptography is not installed, use of crypto disabled

cryptography is not installed, use of crypto disabled

cryptography is not installed, use of crypto disabled

pyqtgraph or numpy are not installed, use of graph feature disabled

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/bin/opcua-client", line 9, in <module>

    load_entry_point('opcua-client==0.8.0', 'console_scripts', 'opcua-client')()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point

    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in load_entry_point

    return ep.load()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load

    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/uaclient/mainwindow.py", line 23, in <module>

    from uawidgets.attrs_widget import AttrsWidget

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/uawidgets/attrs_widget.py", line 11, in <module>

    from uawidgets.get_node_dialog import GetNodeButton

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/uawidgets/get_node_dialog.py", line 7, in <module>

    from uawidgets.tree_widget import TreeWidget

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/uawidgets/tree_widget.py", line 62

    raise ValueError(f"Node {node} not found in tree")

                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have download all the dependencies with pip. anyone know what to do with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the error trace it seems you are using python 3.4, but the `raise ValueError` uses [f-Strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) format that is supported starting from python 3.6.

Try to upgrade your python version.